# VARCHAR(1) vs BOOLEAN

Tags: java, hibernate, sqldatatypes

Is it a good idea to hold a VARCHAR(1) in the db with '0' for false and '1' for true? I don't think so, but it is common practice in the company I am working at the moment. Entities look like

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "my_field")
    private String myField;

    // getter-setter

}
```

Wouldn't it be better to use BOOLEAN? I have never done this before, how does this work together with hibernate?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "my_field")
    private boolean myField;

    // getter-setter

}
```

Is this all that is needed?

Comment: If you want some [true/false/file_not_found situation](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_) then yeah it's a good idea to use a VARCHAR(1)

Comment: It is not bad to use `VARCHAR(1)` as the database type, but it is rather strange to use `String` instead of `boolean`, because the used database mapper should map that correctly. Some also use a number for 1 and 0, but this can also mapped by Hibernate.

Comment: `boolean` best; possibly - at 2nd place - `Boolean` for any NULL scenario I think there is not need for any justification even.

Comment: I meet some DBA, who preferred 'Y', 'N' and NULL, so, maybe it is good idea leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple rule of thumb: when it surprises an experienced reader, it is bad practice.

Caveat: a well-known practice within a company might not surprise the experienced users of that company. But you still have that "surprise" problem; for example when new people get into that team/company.

The real problem with this approach: it forces your **code** to have knowledge that would not be required otherwise! Meaning: *code* defines the meaning of that database entry. When the database field **has** boolean type, there is no interpretation whatsoever required on top of that.